# Create a hit on Amazon Mechnical Turk using ExternalQuestion with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

This question has been asked before, but the answers only contain a little bit of the answer.

**The problem:**

How do I create an hit using an `ExternalQuestion` using the boto3 api?

**Common issues**

Maybe externalQuestions isn't defined yet, as it's not a part of boto3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createTask.py", line 21, in <module>
    question = ExternalQuestion(external_url=question_target, frame_height=800)
NameError: name 'ExternalQuestion' is not defined
```

Or, if you have managed to created an `ExternalQuestion` datamodel,the `create_hit` might still return the following error stating that the `ExternalQuestion` is the wrong datatype.

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: 
Invalid type for parameter Question, value: <mturk.utils.ExternalQuestion instance at 0x70b2560>, type: <type 'instance'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step one: Create a correct `ExternalQuestion` datamodel.**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903989/7052826) shows how to do this first part.

```
class ExternalQuestion:
    """
    An object for constructing an External Question.
    """
    schema_url = "http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd"
    template = '<ExternalQuestion xmlns="%(schema_url)s"><ExternalURL>%%(external_url)s</ExternalURL><FrameHeight>%%(frame_height)s</FrameHeight></ExternalQuestion>' % vars()

    def __init__(self, external_url, frame_height):
        self.external_url = external_url
        self.frame_height = frame_height

    def get_as_params(self, label='ExternalQuestion'):
        return {label: self.get_as_xml()}

    def get_as_xml(self):
        return self.template % vars(self)
```

Then, we create an instance of `ExternalQuestion` as follows:

```
 external_question = ExternalQuestion(
     external_url='www.google.com',
     frame_height=2200
 )
```

**Step 2. Create the hit**

Now that we have the hit, we can submit it using `create_hit` or with `create_hit_with_with_type`. But the tricky part, the Question argument, which must be supplied with the `ExternalQuestion` instance, needs to be a basestring. The documentations are a hazy on this. [I only figured it out because of this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56397390/7052826)

```
 client.create_hit_with_hit_type(
     Question = external_question.get_as_xml()
     # all the other required arguments
 )
```